# Show Related Fields in View

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

Within a Dynamics 365 setup, I have 3 entities related like this:

`Quotes >0----|| Counterparties ||----0< Facilities`
and
`Quotes >0----|< Facilities`

In text, Quotes has a N:1 relationship with Counterparties and a N:N relationship with Facilities. Counterparties has a 1:N relationship with facilities.

I am trying to construct a view that might look like this:

`Quote Date | Quote $ | Counterparty Name | Facility Address
2018-01-15  | 500.25  | ABC Company       | 123 Main St
2018-01-15  | 500.25  | ABC Company       | 200 Main St
2018-02-28  |  79.30  | Different Co      | 5 N Pole Dr
2018-05-05  | 902.99  | Third Inc         | 654 Accent St
2018-05-05  | 902.99  | Third Inc         | 655 Accent St
2018-05-05  | 902.99  | Third Inc         | 656 Accent St
2018-05-05  | 902.99  | Third Inc         | 657 Accent St`

When I start the view on the entities:

- Counterparty entity view can't reference data from either Quotes or Facilities
- Quotes entity view can reference Counterparty but not Facilities
- Facilities entity view can reference Counterparty but not Quotes

Is there a way I can obtain all 3 in one view?

Context: We are migrating from an onsite Dynamics installation to online Dynamics 365. A view like this was previously used to feed several business processes, except it's data source was the underlying database behind the onsite installation.

EDIT: the equivalent SQL code would be this. The where clauses change by use, but I'm just trying to create the master list to filter later:

`select quote.date, quote.amount, counterparty.name, facility.address 
from  quote inner join counterparty on quote.counterparty_id = counterparty.id 
            inner join facility on facility.counterparty_id = counterparty.id`

Comment: Share the sql query used to generate this view. We can check equivalent fetchxml option.

Answer (score 0):

I just feed your sql query into [free online converter tool](http://www.sql2fetchxml.com) & got this.

```
<fetch mapping="logical" version="1.0">
  <entity name="quote">
    <attribute name="date" />
    <attribute name="amount" />
    <link-entity name="counterparty" from="id" to="counterparty_id" link-type="inner">
      <attribute name="name" />
      <link-entity name="facility" from="counterparty_id" to="id" link-type="inner">
        <attribute name="address" />
      </link-entity>
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamics' views work well with N:1 relationship but with N:N and 1:N, it's more difficult to get what you want.

Try adding a new lookup in Quote pointing to Facility. Then you can make a view from Quote and add the columns you need. How do you manage N:N? Manual or Native?